# Disable Shutdown and Restart for ALL users

Tags: ssh, dconf, gsettings

I run a small computer lab for students, consisting of 8 computers running Ubuntu 16.04.4.

The students are not used to Linux, so they often confuse *Logout* with *Restart* and *Shutdown*, effectively disrupting the Lab's work flow (some work is done remotely).

I tried following the instructions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53308/remove-shutdown-suspend-restart-and-hibernate-from-the-user-switcher-menu), but I have to repeat it using DConf Editor via the GUI for each and every user.

Executing the `gsettings` commands via SSH spits out the following error:

```
dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf:Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

I plan to implement the solution by running a Bash script via SSH on each of the computers.

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: How about creating student user with very low permissions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Gsettings via remote shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457016/how-to-change-gsettings-via-remote-shell)

Comment: I would rather recommend [the Policy Kit route](/a/187345/175814) though if that still works in Xenial.

Comment: @SmitTheLastFirefoxUser: That won't help. The "regular" user privileges in Ubuntu include the permission to suspend, shut down and restart the system from a local session. One can remove that permission via Policy Kit as recommended in my previous comment.